# Память под контейнеры выделяется в стеки или куче?

Tags: c++

как выделяется память под контейнеры vector, map в с++

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Под элементы контейнера - в куче.<sup>1 2</sup>

Под сам контейнер - так же, как для любого другого объекта, это зависит от того, как он создан:

- `new std::vector<int>` - в куче
- `void foo() {std::vector<int> vec;}` - в стеке
- ...

---

<sup>1</sup> По умолчанию. Написав свой аллокатор, элементы можно поместить куда угодно.

<sup>2</sup> Большинство реализаций `std::string` не выделяют буфер в куче, если в них немного элементов (не больше пары десятков). В таком случае символы хранятся в самом объекте контейнера. Насколько я знаю, другие стандартные контейнеры так не делают.

Comment: Некоторые контейнеры хранят буфер, чтобы при малом количестве элементов не обращаться к распределителью(не знаю на счет вектора, но string так реализован кажется)

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Про `std::string` - добавил.

Comment: Хотя `std::string` хранит символьные типы, он может позволить себе иметь буфер для символов,  а  для контейнеров, хранящие любой тип(например вектор), это нереализуемо